# How to use Chartjs to plot a single row of colored bars with a time based x axis

Tags: chart.js

I have some time based data I want a graphical representation of, and was hoping to use Chartjs to plot this.

The data looks something like the following:

```
Time    State   
--------------
7am     up
9am     down
10.45am out
17.35   up
```

Also, each "state" will have its own color, so I would use this as a bar color when using a bar graph

```
up =    red
down =  yellow
out =   green
```

The end result I am after is a simple one row bar like the following...

[image]

I thought I may be able to use a Chartjs `horizontal stacked` bar chart (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#horizontal-bar-chart) to do this somehow, but I just can't work out how to get this working.

Some (not working) experimental code is as follows:

```
    private createChart(): void {
        if (this.chart !== undefined) {
          return;
        }

        Chart.register(BarController, PointElement, Tooltip, Legend, TimeScale, LinearScale, CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement);
        const options: ChartOptions = {
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },
            title: {
              display: false,
            },
          },

          indexAxis: 'y',
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          scales: {
            y: {
              stacked: true,
              type: 'time',
              display: true,
              // position: 'bottom',
              time: {
                unit: 'minute',
                displayFormats: {
                  minute: 'h:mm a'
                }
              }
            },
            x: {
              stacked: false,
              
             }
          }    
        };

        this.chart = new Chart(this.canvasRef.nativeElement, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: this.chartData,
          options
        });

        this.chart.config.options.scales.y.min = new Date('2023-02-13T06:19:31.842Z').getTime();
         
        const labels = [
          'up',
          'down'
          // 'Dataset 2'
        ];

        
        const d1 = new Date('2023-02-13T06:20:32.842Z').getTime();
        const d2 = new Date('2023-02-13T06:21:33.842Z').getTime();
        this.chartData = {
          labels,
          datasets: [{
            label: 'up',
            data: [{x: 10, y: d1}],
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          },
          {
             label: 'down',
             data: [{x: 20, y: d2}],
              backgroundColor: 'green',
           }
        ]
        };

        this.chart.update();
      }
```

In the above I have tried various combinations of labels, x values, y values, data shapes, but I only even get an empty graph.

Perhaps this is not really possible (I am trying to use the wrong component).

How can I achieve this using chartjs?

### Update

Using example from @winner_joiner below, I have put a copy of it at [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LOJh5SRXs6kgGFno?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview) and have tried to use the time in the x axis, but can see it is still not plotting the bars using the dates as the length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your code basically works, here a slightly modified version of your code.

After your comments and updated question, I reworke the example *(seen below)*. Although it is possible to do with chart.js the question is, maybe for this specific task a different library or solution would be better/more convenient.

**Update Chart, with some *similar* values from your question:**
*(I'm using here momentjs, since it is recommend usually needed form date/time actions in chartjs, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html))*

```js
const d0 = moment.duration('07:00:00').asMinutes();
const d1 = moment.duration('09:00:00').asMinutes();
const d2 = moment.duration('10:45:00').asMinutes();
const d3 = moment.duration('17:35:00').asMinutes();
const d4 = moment.duration('19:00:00').asMinutes();
let values = [d0, d1, d2, d3, d4];

let data = {
    labels: [''],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'up',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d1],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },{
      label: 'down',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d2],
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },{
      label: 'out',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d3],
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    },{
      label: 'up',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d4],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
  ]
  };

const config = {
data,
type: 'bar',
    options:{
      plugins: {
        tooltip: {
           mode: 'dataset',
           callbacks: {
            label: function(item){
               return moment().startOf('day').add({ minute: item.raw}).format('HH:mm');
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        title: {
          display: false,
        },
    },
    indexAxis: 'y',
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        min: d0,
        ticks: {
            callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                return moment().startOf('day').add({ minute: value}).format('HH:mm');
            }
        },
        afterBuildTicks: axis => axis.ticks = values.map(v => ({ value: v }))
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      },
    }
  }};
  
  new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>    
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>   
<div class="chart" style="height:184px; width:350px;">
    <canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The only thing I was actually wanting the **time** (in the case the y value, d1 and d2)  on the x axis, where as what we have here is still the x (i.e. the 10 and 20). It was when I was trying to get time down there that I was having issues. The 10 and 20 are not actually values I need to plot anywhere - I have them in my original example just as I was experimenting.

Comment: I have taken your example, and put it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/LOJh5SRXs6kgGFno?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview), and put the time as the x. I now get time on the x axis, and the first time is correct but not the second (the green), it is just plotting 2 equally length bars

Comment: Actually in my example, the first time is not correct either (I was mistaken). The bars don't seem to be looking at the datetime values at all.

Comment: @peterc I Updated my question, I hope this code snippet can help you with finding your solution.

Comment: thankyou! This is very close. I Just wonder why the tooltip when you hover seems to be out of sync when using the above?

Comment: Ah, by trial and error, can get the tooltip working correct by adding `tooltip: {
         mode: 'dataset'  
      },` At any rate I will mark as the answer, thankyou very much!