# Skip chartjs tick label if they overlap

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This is the final piece following on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75455765/how-to-remove-all-gridlines-border-and-show-only-ticks-on-a-chartjs-horizontal/75456132#75456132)

I have the following (ongoing) chartjs setup (thanks to @winnder_joiner)

```
    const d0 = new Date("2023-02-15T00:00:00.721Z").getTime()
    const d1 = new Date("2023-02-15T00:03:00.721Z").getTime()
    const d2 = new Date("2023-02-15T02:30:00.721Z").getTime()
    const d3 = new Date("2023-02-15T03:20:00.721Z").getTime()
    const d4 = new Date("2023-02-15T05:05:00.721Z").getTime()
    let values = [d0, d1, d2, d3, d4];

    let data = {
        labels: [''],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'up',
          axis: 'y',
          data: [d1],
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        },{
          label: 'down',
          //axis: 'y',
          data: [d2],
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        },{
          label: 'out',
         // axis: 'y',
          data: [d3],
          backgroundColor: 'green',
        },{
          label: 'up',
       //   axis: 'y',
          data: [d4],
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        }
      ]
      };

    const config = {
    data,
    type: 'bar',
        options:{
          elements: {
            bar: {
              borderWidth: 0
            }
          },
          ticks: {
              display: true
            },

          interaction: {
                mode: 'dataset'
            },
          // tooltip: {
          //    mode: 'dataset'  
          // },
          hover: {
               mode: 'dataset'            
            },      
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
          title: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
        indexAxis: 'y',
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
           x: {
             border: {
             display: false,
          },
        
            min: d0,
            ticks: {
               source: 'auto',
                maxRotation: 80,
                minRotation: 60,
                autoSkip: false,   
             // autoSkipPadding: 0,
              //padding: 0,
              //align: 'inner',
              //crossAlign: 'near',
                callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                    return moment(value).format('HH:mm');
                }
            },
            afterBuildTicks: axis => axis.ticks = values.map(v => ({ value: v }))
          },
          y: {
             grid: {
              display: false
            },
            
            stacked: true
          },
        }    
      }};
      
      new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), config);
```

This can also be seen [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bxHaKZx75ZFQgA7L)

The callback `afterBuildTicks` allows the ticks to be draw at the actual data points - which is good. If we don't use `afterBuildTicks` it just automatically works out some points to draw the ticks.

The only problem occurs if two data points happen to be very close, eg we get the lables overlapping....

[image]

My question here is..
Is there any way to have it skip drawing the ticks label if there is such an overlap?

Comment: I think "autoSkip: false" is generating that. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well As far as I know, you can prevent the overlap with the config *(more than you already did)*, BUT you could do it yourself just calculating the diff between the ticks. You would have to *eyeball* die `minDiff`, and in the tick generation return null if the ticks are too close.

**I tried it in the following example:**
*(It is not prefect, because if there are many after each other, that are too short, "too many" ticks might be skipped)*

> *In this example `11:29` could/should be shown, because `11:00` was not displayed.*

```js
const d0 = moment.duration('08:50:00').asMinutes();
const d1 = moment.duration('09:00:00').asMinutes();
const d2 = moment.duration('10:45:00').asMinutes();
const d22 = moment.duration('11:00:00').asMinutes();
const d23 = moment.duration('11:29:00').asMinutes();
const d3 = moment.duration('17:35:00').asMinutes();
const d4 = moment.duration('19:00:00').asMinutes();
let values = [d0, d1, d2, d22, d23, d3, d4];

let data = {
    labels: [''],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'up',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d1],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },{
      label: 'down',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d2],
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },{
      label: 'uppsy',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d22],
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    },{
      label: 'uppsy1',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d23],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },{
      label: 'out',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d3],
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },{
      label: 'up',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d4],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
  ]
  };

const config = {
data,
type: 'bar',
    options:{
       plugins: {
        tooltip: {
           mode: 'dataset',
           callbacks: {
            label: function(item){
               return moment().startOf('day').add({ minute: item.raw}).format('HH:mm');
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        title: {
          display: false,
        },
    },
    indexAxis: 'y',
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        min: d0,
        border: { display: false },
        ticks: {
            source: 'auto',
            maxRotation: 80,
            minRotation: 60,
            autoSkip: false, 
            callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                let minDiff = 30;
                if(index > 0 && value - ticks[index-1].value < minDiff){
                console.info(ticks[index-1].value  - value )
                    return null;
                }
                return moment().startOf('day').add({ minute: value}).format('HH:mm');
            }
        },
        afterBuildTicks: axis => axis.ticks = values.map(v => ({ value: v }))
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        grid: { display: false },
      },
    }
  }};
  
  new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>    
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>   
<div class="chart" style="height:84px; width:350px;">
    <canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```

**Update -*maybe better solution*:**

You could filter the possible ticks before drawing the ticks, this makes it easier to see, if the `minDiff` is applied in the correct manner.

```
values = values.reduce( (pre, curr, index) => {
    if(index == 0 || (curr - pre[pre.length-1] > minDiff )){
        pre.push(curr);
    } 
    return pre;
}, [])
```

**Here the full working demo:**

```js
const d0 = moment.duration('08:50:00').asMinutes();
const d1 = moment.duration('09:00:00').asMinutes();
const d2 = moment.duration('10:45:00').asMinutes();
const d22 = moment.duration('11:00:00').asMinutes();
const d23 = moment.duration('11:29:00').asMinutes();
const d3 = moment.duration('17:35:00').asMinutes();
const d4 = moment.duration('19:00:00').asMinutes();

let minDiff = 30;
let values = [d0, d1, d2, d22, d23, d3, d4];

/* prepare the ticks */
values = values.reduce( (pre, curr, index) => {
    if(index == 0 || (curr - pre[pre.length-1] > minDiff )){
        pre.push(curr);
    } 
    return pre;
}, [])

let data = {
    labels: [''],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'up',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d1],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },{
      label: 'down',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d2],
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },{
      label: 'uppsy',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d22],
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    },{
      label: 'uppsy1',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d23],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },{
      label: 'out',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d3],
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },{
      label: 'up',
      axis: 'y',
      data: [d4],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
  ]
  };

const config = {
data,
type: 'bar',
    options:{
       plugins: {
        tooltip: {
           mode: 'dataset',
           callbacks: {
            label: function(item){
               return moment().startOf('day').add({ minute: item.raw}).format('HH:mm');
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        title: {
          display: false,
        },
    },
    indexAxis: 'y',
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        min: d0,
        border: { display: false },
        ticks: {
            source: 'auto',
            maxRotation: 80,
            minRotation: 60,
            autoSkip: false, 
            callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                return moment().startOf('day').add({ minute: value}).format('HH:mm');
            }
        },
        afterBuildTicks: axis => axis.ticks = values.map(v => ({ value: v }))
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        grid: { display: false },
      },
    }
  }};
  
  new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>    
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>   
<div class="chart" style="height:84px; width:350px;">
    <canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like can work, thanks again!

Comment: @peterc sure thing no problem, good to here that it can solve your problem :)